# Classes events on change, pharo

Tags: pharo

Is it possible to listen events that classes throw when changed? I need to know when something (code, variables, etc) changes in some classes from the system browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pay attention since Pharo 2.0, there is now a SystemAnnouncer that emits announcements. There is not SystemChangeNotifier anymore.

```
 SystemAnnouncer uniqueInstance
```

is the way to access it. Then look in the package System-Announcements

You can register using

```
SystemAnnouncer uniqueInstance on: ClassRenamed do: [ doSomething ]
```

or

```
SystemAnnouncer uniqueInstance on: ClassRenamed send: #foo to: anObject
```

You can unsubscribe using

```
SystemAnnouncer uniqueInstanceunsubscribe: anObject
```

Answer (score 4):

`SystemChangeNotifier uniqueInstance` is the object managing the system change events (to which code and variable changes belong). Have a look at the references to `SystemChangeNotifier` to find many example users.

For example, to be notified about all changes (other registration methods are available that only register for a subset of changes):

```
SystemChangeNotifier uniqueInstance
  notify: self ofAllSystemChangesUsing: #systemEvent:
```

The method `systemEvent:` is from now on called with instances of subclasses of `AbstractEvent` representing all changes.

To get rid of the further notifications execute:

```
SystemChangeNotifier uniqueInstance
  noMoreNotificationsFor: self
```

Comment: It worked ok! but i think i should 'subscribe' for some particular events, for instance, changes only done to a specific class. can this be done?
Anyway, i can keep working now, but i dont like doing useless changes for every modification I do at any class.

Comment: Note the above solution refers to Pharo 1.3 an earlier.